# My view page is not displaying anything in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a beginner in asp.net core. I am using the **code first** approach to create a view page called CreateCustomerAccount.cshtml and I have added the controller to return the view called CreateCustomerAccountController. However, the controller is returning blank page instead of the html/view content. Have I done anything wrong?

Here is my code for CreateAccount.cshtml

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "CreateCustomerAccount";
}

<h2>CreateCustomerAccount</h2>  

<p>User can create account using a form later</p>
```

And here is my code for my CreateCustomerAccountController.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TimeSheetManagementSystem.Controllers
{
public class CreateCustomerAccountController : Controller
{
public IActionResult Index()
{
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult CreateCustomerAccount()
    {
        return View();
    }


  }
  }
```

Comment: Your View should be under folder named "CreateCustomerAccountController" and your view/page should be named "Index.cshtml" or "CreateCustomerAccount.cshtml", do you have the same structure?

Comment: Your method is named `Index()` so you view needs to be named `Index.cshtml` (`CreateCustomerAccount` is the name of your controller, not the method). Alternatively you can use `return View("CreateCustomerAccount");` but that would make no sense

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my view name to index and added   "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;" and it works

Answer (score 0):

The controller name and action result name should be different Change action result name and re-create view with this actin name this will work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TimeSheetManagementSystem.Controllers
{
public class CreateCustomerAccountController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }

 public ActionResult CreateCustomerAccountt()
 {
    return View();
 }


 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my view name to index and added "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;" and it works